# bootstrap form does not send post method

Tags: http-post, forms, twitter-bootstrap-form

I have bug with my bootstrap form, when I click on submit button the POST method never trigger, the form is in a loop cycle, I need to send the data typed by user to "addsoporte.php" script but it never happens, my code is this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(@$_SESSION[ 'autorizado' ] != "si"){
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Agregar Solicitud de Soporte</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS File  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <LINK tpe='text/css' rel='StyleSheet' href='marn.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 class="page-header text-center">Solicitud de Soporte Tecnico</h1>
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="nuesoporte-form" role="form" method="post" action "addsoporte.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtdessop" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripcion</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="txtdessop" 
                                placeholder="Descripcion de la Solicitud del Soporte"></textarea>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtmodsop" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Modulo Afectado</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control" id="txtmodsop">
                                        <option hidden>Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option>Estadisticas</option>
                                        <option>Indicadores</option>
                                        <option>Inv. Estadisticas</option>
                                        <option>Metodologia</option>
                                        <option>Glosario</option>
                                        <option>Publicaciones</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                </select>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <a href='javascript: history.go(-1)' id="cancelar" name="cancelar" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</a>
                            <input type="submit" name="cmdenviarsoporte" value="Enviar Solicitud" class="btn btn-primary btn-clock" />                                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>     
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Your suggestions will be welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe to late. But you forgot the "=" behind the "action".